# Complement of the kernel of a group epimorphism of a semidirect product

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, semidirect-product, wreath-product

Currently, I am going through Chapter 25 of [Character theory of finite groups](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=GjyWI91FAZQC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=Character%20theory%20of%20finite%20groups&ots=4lExSdAZAq&sig=knazW3rtYizIjo6Z1wnX2o4JQFw#v=onepage&q=Character%20theory%20of%20finite%20groups&f=false) by Bertram Huppert.

Here the authors introduce the concept of semidirect product $G \wr H$ and the kernel of its epimorphism as follows.

> $$G \wr H = \{(f, h) | h \in H, f:\Omega \to H\}$$
>
> and the product is
>
> $$(f_1, h_1) (f_2, h_2) = (f, h_1 h_2)$$
>
> where
>
> $$ f (j) = f_1(j) f_2(jh_1)  $$ for $j \in \Omega$.
>
> Now, $\alpha$ with $(f, h) \alpha = h$ is an epimorphism of $G \wr H$
>   onto $H$ and  $$ \ker \alpha = B =  \{(f, 1) | f: \Omega \to G\} $$ is
>   isomorphic to $G \times \underset{n}{\ldots} \times G$.
>
> $B$ has a complement  $$ \overline{H} = \{(e, h) | h \in H\} $$ in $G
>  \wr H$, where $e(j) = 1$ for all $j \in \Omega$ and $\overline{H}
>  \cong H$.

**My question:**

Why is the complement of $B$ is not $\overline{B}$?